# \unskip and \hskip in \linebreak

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, tex-core

I found the definition of `\linebreak` macro as follows:

```
\def\linebreak{\@testopt{\@no@lnbk-}4}

\def\@no@lnbk #1[#2]{%
  \ifvmode
    \@nolnerr
  \else
    \@tempskipa\lastskip
    \unskip
    \penalty #1\@getpen{#2}%
    \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@
      \hskip\@tempskipa
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
\fi}
```

I don't understand why `\linebreak` need to save `\lastskip` and restore it after the penalty item? Could someone give some examples for explaining why these are necessary?

Comment: Read section **16.2 Chris’ comments** of [`source2e.pdf`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (p 48 onward).

Comment: @Werner It seems Chris' comments are mainly about the deficiencies of current algorithm. I still don't know, for example, why `hello\hskip1em\linebreak world` is expanded to `hello\break\hskip1em world`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A glue after a non discardable item is a feasible break point. If `\linebreak` was defined just by

```
\penalty#1
```

(where the amount of penalty is determined by the optional argument to `\linebreak` or the default if no argument is passed) an input such as

```
hello \linebreak world
```

would simply ignore the penalty if the space after `hello` turns out to be a good line break point.

Not really important for `\linebreak`, but decisive for `\nolinebreak` that uses the same `\@no@lnbk` internal macro.

So LaTeX “transfers” whatever glue it finds when `\linebreak` or `\nolinebreak` is found *after* the penalty; such a glue will never be a feasible break point, because it's preceded by a penalty which is a discardable item.

Note also that the same internal macro is used by `\pagebreak` and `\nopagebreak`; the mechanism is exactly the same.

Comment: the "not really important" distinction between  `linebreak` and `\nolinebreak` is true if no optional arg is used. If an option is used then they are far more similar, both making consitional line break points.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you have `<skip><negative penalty>`, then if the skip is a good break point, it will be used; otherwise the penalty would be examined. In any case `<skip>\penalty-10000` would result in a break. That's what I meant with “not really important”.